# Devexpress winform PDFViewer Zoom In and Zoom Out

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, pdfviewer

Using PDFViewer1 how would one implement their own zoom-in and zoom-out controls?

I have Zoom-In and Zoom-Out picturebox graphics on my form, that when clicked I want to either zoom in or zoom out respectively.

I program in VB.net using Visual Studio 2012

In my feeble attempt this is what I have:

```
Private Sub Zoom_In_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Zoom_In.Click
    Me.PdfViewer1.ZoomMode = PdfZoomMode.Custom
    Me.PdfViewer1.ZoomFactor = 120
    Me.PdfViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction using either
VB or C#, thanks for your help.

Comment: DevExpress has one of the best support people/policy I ever came across. I cannot imagine a single case where I got no answer. So why ask here on SO when you can get the real thing directly from DevExpress?

Comment: Appreciate your response Uwe. I have posted the question on DevExpress forums yesterday and have had no response as of yet. I need an answer  as soon as possible. Knowing that the StackOverflow community is quite large I posted here as well, hoping for an answer sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PdfZoomInCommand](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPdfViewerCommandsPdfZoomInCommandClassPropTopic)/[PdfZoomOUtCommand](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraPdfViewerCommandsPdfZoomOutCommandtopic) commands:

```
PdfViewerCommand zoomIn;
PdfViewerCommand zoomOut;
//...
    zoomIn = new PdfZoomInCommand(pdfViewer1);
    zoomOut = new PdfZoomOutCommand(pdfViewer1);
//...
void buttonZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(zoomIn.CanExecute())
        zoomIn.Execute();
}
void buttonZoomOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(zoomOut.CanExecute())
        zoomOut.Execute();
}
```